# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id') in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I learn something new, I usually write code, in which I can use it, but I try this code to be as simple as possible.
Now I am learning the basics of JsonWebToken, so I have made a very small database in MongoDB - just a couple of documents with 3 fields - _id, name, age and username. Then I wrote a few lines of code in node.js, but the problem is that I always receive "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')". If I leave the payload empty( by removing 'doc._id') then I get a response
with the security token, but the data property in it is null - "data": {"user": null}. Can you tell where the problem lies?
Here is the code with only the final lines missig ('mongoose.connect...' etc.)

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    age: { type: Number, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true }, 
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

function login(req, res){ 
User.findOne({  username })
    .then(function(doc){ 
        const token = jwt.sign({ doc._id }, 'abc123', {expiresIn: 250});
        return res.status(200).json({status: 'success', token, data: {doc}}); 
    });                     
}

app.post('/login', login);
```

Does anyone have a clue how to get the actual data of the user in the response?

Comment: Pretty simple... `username` is not defined and `findOne({ username })` is resolving with `null` because it can't find any matches

Comment: If that was the case I would have received a reference error that username was undefined. I forgot to tell that I use postman to get the request, I choose raw and JSON and I write in the body just {"username": "george15"} or {"username": "john25"}, because the database I made is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending a payload via Postman then you need to access the `req.body` object in your `User.findOne` function like so:

```js
User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
//...
//...
```

At the minute `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id')"`. is from trying to read `doc._id`. It's null because there were no matches for `{username: undefined}`.

Comment: I have just done what you advised me to do.  Now I did not get a response at all. Not even an error message

Comment: @MiriyanAsenov I have just answered your other question which has a few more things to help you.